# Python Parse Arguments if Flag not provided

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have configured the option below :

```
parser.add_argument('-f', '--files', dest='files', nargs='*', metavar='', default=sys.stdin,
                    help='File List to Search In')
```

And it works perfectly fine when running :

```
% script.py -f file1 file2 ....
```

But i also want to support execution without the `-f` flag

Meaning :

```
% script.py file1 file2 ...
```

I tried to do it with positional argument , but it is mandatory and keeps interfering even if `-f` is introduced in the commanding.

Clerefication:
i got additional parsed arguments meaning sometime the execution can be

% script.py -m -g -r -f file1 file2 ....
So i cant see how using sys.argv[1:] will help me.

i need specifically the option to when -f is not written but file names are.

Answer (score 0):

You can access terminal args using `sys.argv`

`script.py`:

```
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.argv[1:]
```

Then run:

```
% python script.py file1 file2
```

OUT

```
['file1', 'file2']
```

Comment: It will work only if i dont have other arguments . 
In my case i got several arguments that each set with a flag -f -t -r etc....
so argv[]  wont work

Comment: Then use argparse

Comment: That's what I'm doing... 
Please read my question again

Comment: Clarified my question

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by defining another positioned argument

parser.add_argument('-f', '--files', dest='files', nargs='+', metavar='', help='File List to Search In')
parser.add_argument(dest='files2', nargs='*', metavar='', default=False)

And passing "False" as a default value in case it gets no value .

afterwards i just run a simple check

if args.files2:
file_list = args.files2
else:
file_list = args.files

this way file_list will contain the file names doesn`t matter if it came from the positioned argument or the -f argument.